# como habilitar el evento de un boton creado dinamicamente luego de traer los datos por json?

Tags: jquery, json, nodejs, express, mongoose

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo se hace para habilitar que funcione nuevamente un botón que se creó después de hacer fetch y traerme por json unos documentos del servidor.

Sabemos que se hace un preventdefault para que no recargue la pagina, y me trae los artículos del caso.

Ahora quiero que por ejemplo en una tabla como la que mostrare a cada articulo tengo para añadir ese articulo copiando los datos

```
$('#idcaso').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            var valor= $('#idcaso option:selected').val()

            var url=`/actdiarias/json/${valor}`;

            console.log(url)
            fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(datos =>{ 
                $('#genid').val(datos._id);
                $('#tienda').val(datos.tienda.nombre);
                $('#statustitulo').val(datos.status.titulo)
                $('#statusdescripcion').val(datos.status.descripcion)

                var creatabla1 = `<table id= "tb" class="table table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Articulo <strong class="text-black bg-warning"> selecciona un articulo! </strong></th>
                            <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                            <th scope="col">Reporte</th>
                            <th scope="col">id</th>
                            <th scope="col">operacion</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> </tbody>
                        </table>` 

                        $('#muestradetalle').append(creatabla1)     

                if (datos===null) {
                    $('#muestradetalle').html('no se encontraron resultados...')
                    console.log('no hayaste nada')
                    return false;
                }
                var indice=0
                 for (item in datos.articulos) {
                        indice++

                    var creatabla = `
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="row">${[indice]}</th>
                            <td>${datos.articulos[item].descripcion}</td>
                            <td>${datos.articulos[item].codigo}</td>
                            <td>${datos.articulos[item].reporte}</td>
                            <td>${datos.articulos[item]._id}</td>

                            <td><button id="uhm"> explorar</button></td>

                            </tr>
                        `
                        $('#tb tbody').append(creatabla)
                }   


            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            $('#muestradetalle').empty().append('')
        });
$('#uhm').on('click', function (e) {
        alert('hola')
        var seleccionado = datos.articulos.filter((articulo) => {
            if(articulo._id ===datos.articulos[item]._id){
                return true
            }
            else{
                return 'no encontrado'
            }
        console.log(seleccionado)
        })
```

Es necesario que vuelva a hacer una petición json al servidor? aunque ya lo hice el problema radica en que ese botón creado a partir de datos solicitados por json ya no tienen la misma autoridad que los que están en el documentos creados fuera de la consulta json, lo probé con un alert y efectivamente el alert funciona con botones que no están creados dinámicamente, como hago para que me funcionen ? mi objetivo es que cuando me cargue los artículos de un caso que haya seleccionado en el select poder seleccionar un articulo de esos y procesar la actividad con ese solo articulo copiando la info de la tabla de solo ese articulo para que cuando liste las actividades me aparezca que revise solo ese articulo en ese momento, ayuda please que me voy a volver loco :L

Comment: por favor, pon más cuidado en la redacción. Si no, es difícil comprender qué quieres hacer

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes incorporar tu evento al crear el botón dinamicamente. Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como puedes hacerlo. Saludos!

```js
var articulos = [
  {id:1, nombre:"articulo 1", precio:"$1"},
  {id:2, nombre:"articulo 2", precio:"$2"},
  {id:3, nombre:"articulo 3", precio:"$3"},
  {id:4, nombre:"articulo 4", precio:"$4"},
  {id:5, nombre:"articulo 5", precio:"$5"},
];

function createTable(){

let table = `
  <table id="tblProductos">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Operaciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblProductosBody">

    </tbody>
  </table>
  `;

$('#container').append(table);

  articulos.forEach(item => {
      let row = ` 
        <tr>
          <td>${item.id}</td>
          <td>${item.nombre}</td>
          <td>${item.precio}</td>
          <td><button onclick='eliminarProducto(${JSON.stringify(item)})'>Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>    
      `;
     
     $('#container tbody').append(row);       
  });   
}

function eliminarProducto(item){
//Una muestra del objeto que recibo como parámetro.
console.log("Recibiendo objeto: ",item);
//Una muestra de como acceder a sus atributos.
console.log("Accediendo al nombre de ",item.nombre)
}
createTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: si amigo entiendo pero quisiera es copiar la info del objeto seleccionado para pasarlo al formulario, un simple copy paste de un lado a otro para cuando seleccione uno de la lista,subi una imagen de ref, cuando le de al boton agregar quiero que se me copie la info del codigo, la descripcion y el reporte con que llego el articulo al formulario para generar la actividad en base a ese solo articulo. pero esa lista se genera con un fetch para traerme los datos, es una relacion embebida con mongoose donde un caso tiene muchos articulos pero quiero trabajar solo con uno, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: mmm no entiendo. En tu evento, ya tienes el objeto del articulo seleccionado. Solo resta cargar el form con estos datos.

Comment: si pero el detalle es que intento dos cosas y ninguna me sale, la primera que veo redundante que es pedir una consulta donde solo venga el articulo que se  selecciono enviando el id pero me sale mal porque cuando se genera el nuevo boton no me hace el preventdefault ni ninguna accion. la otra es organizar lo que ya me traje pero no se como plantearlo bien porque seria simular lo que hace una base de datos pero no se bien como plantearlo.

Comment: te doy un ejemplo de los datos que me vienen me lista que tiene 5 articulos pero cual seria la mejor manera de representar en el front ya con todos los datos, seleccionar uno bien sea por medio de una tabla como lo estoy haciendo (que lo veo mas facil) anadiendo un boton tal como en la captura y luego pasar la info de ese objeto actual al formulario. el detalle es que va por separado del evento click del boton ya que pertenece al fetch que hice de todos los articulos. no se si me explique bien jeje no tengo tanta experiencia con js por eso les pregunto. saludos

Comment: Me parece que te estas ahogando en un vaso de agua. El ejemplo que te di sirve perfectamente. No importa en donde creas tu botón. Solo debes agarrar la funcion **eliminarProducto()** e incorporar el codigo necesario para pasar los datos del objeto que estas recibiendo a un form. Ahora no puedo, pero mas tarde la edito en todo caso para mostrarte como hacerlo. Saludos!

Comment: yo tambien siento eso, pero ya hice como dijiste agregar el evento en linea con el boton , probando un simple alert no va, el misterio esta en que  del boton generado no tiene ningun efecto porque ya se cargo el documento , tengo que buscar es la forma que el boton tenga efecto luego de cargado el documento, estoy probando delegar el evento de otra manera